# How to update all the templates from inside the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this directive "check-Room":

```
.directive('checkRoom',['$rootScope','CalendarService','ModalService','BookingsService','$q','$state', function($rootScope,CalendarService,ModalService,BookingsService,$q,$state){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: 'true',
            scope: {},
            templateUrl: 'templates/calendarWeekDay.html',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

                scope.boxData= $rootScope.arrayDaysInYear[attrs.calendarday][1][attrs.roomname];

                scope.saveBooking=function(){

                    CalendarService.Update(scope.boxData).then(function(){

                        CalendarService.Get().then(function(data){

                           function buildBoxData(){

                           var deferred = $q.defer();  

                           deferred.resolve(BookingsService.YearBookingCalendar(data));

                           return deferred.promise

                            }

                           buildBoxData().then(function(value){

                           $rootScope.arrayDaysInYear = value;

                           scope.boxData = $rootScope.arrayDaysInYear[attrs.calendarday][1][attrs.roomname];

                           $state.reload();

                           scope.closeModal();

                           })
                        })
                    })
                }

               function modalBookingDetail() {
                    ModalService
                        .init('templates/modalBookingDetail.html',scope)
                        .then(function(modal) {
                            modal.show();
                        });
                }

                scope.checkDetails=function(){            
                    modalBookingDetail();

                };  
            }    
        }    
 }]);
```

called several times in my main view:

```
 <table class="bordered">
   <tbody>
     </tr>
       <td check-Room class="outer-border-room"  calendarDay={{day[5]}} roomName="Pantheon">
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td check-Room class="outer-border-room"  calendarDay={{day[5]}} roomName="Colosseo">
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td check-Room class="outer-border-room"  calendarDay={{day[5]}} roomName="Trevi">
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td check-Room class="outer-border-room"  calendarDay={{day[5]}} roomName="Navona">
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

After pulling a modal window with scope.checkDetail() I can insert some data and with scope.saveBooking() I asychronously update the database.
Now I would like to be able to reload not only the selected directive template but all the others templates based on the same directive.
It seems like "$rootScope.arrayDaysInYear = value" and $state.reload() isn't working.

Comment: I found a solution by replacing `$state.reload()` with `$state.go($state.current.name, {}, {reload: true})` but I don't think this is the proper way to update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an event when the data is ready with `$rootScope.$boradcast` and receive it from all of your directive using `$scope.$on`.

See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Comment: there is only one directive called several times. I need to update all the templates. Right now only if I manually refresh the browser page I can see the data updated.